# Solution explorer doesn't show docker compose file

Tags: visual-studio-code, docker-compose

I am developing an Web API application in dotnet core using vs code. I wonder why docker compose file doesn't appear in my solution explorer as the matter of the fact, the file does exist in my file system. Anyone knows why? it's not a big problem but it's annoying sometime to switch back and forth between solution explorer and file system. Thank you for your time.

Is there any way to add docker compose file or any other file to solution explorer?

Comment: Have you tried: ``right client on solution -> add -> existing item`` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone into the context menu of your solution and added Docker Support?, Also What sa-es-ir said Context menu -> add -> existing.. if your resources already exist.